# Migrating class inheriting str and __new__ from py 2 to 2/3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, inheritance

I'm currently attempting to migrate some python 2 code to python 2/3 compatible code and am having trouble with this particular class:

```
class FileID(str):
    def __new__(cls, fileid, *args):
        return super(FileID, cls).__new__(cls, fileid)

    def __init__(self, fileid, size):
        super(FileID, self).__init__(fileid)
        self.size = size

x = FileID('a', 1)

print(x) # prints: a
print(x.size) # prints: 1
```

In python 2.7, this works just fine.

To port over, I've been using `from builtins import super`.

For python 3.6, I'm deleting the redundant inner super arguments, but it seems to balk on both the `__new__` method, and also on passing in an `int` argument (saying it must be `str`).

Is there a way to create this class as py2/3 (inherits `str`, and can accept arguments of type int) that is equivalent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class FileID(str):
    def __new__(cls, fileid, *args):
        return super().__new__(cls, fileid)
    def __init__(self, fileid, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.size = size
x = FileID('a', 1)
print(x) # prints: a
print(x.size) # prints: 1
```

works for me in both python 2 and 3

Comment: Thanks!  Should have seen it earlier.  >.<